# wget looping over directories and subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, wget

Trying to use wget to pull a bunch of files from the below ftp site. There are subdirectories by year, 2010 to 2017, and further subdirs for individual months.  I don't want all the months, just Nov through Apr.

Thought something like the below would work:

```
#! /bin/bash

for months in "11_Nov" "12_Dec" "01_Jan" "02_Feb" "03_Mar" "04_Apr"
do
  wget ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/NOAA/G02158/masked/{2010..2017}/"$months"/*.tar
done
```

but the {2010..2017} bit seems to be tripping it up.  What is the proper syntax?  I feel like I"m really close.

Thanks

Edit: Error is:
No such directory ‘DATASETS/NOAA/G02158/masked/{2010..2017}/12_Dec’.

Edit2: user [xenoid](https://superuser.com/users/670091/xenoid) noted that my shell might not be bash.  Indeed, it was not. It was .tcsh.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: it's always a good idea to post the according error message, so ppl can help faster

Comment: Error is:No such directory ‘DATASETS/NOAA/G02158/masked/{2010..2017}/12_Dec’.

Comment: funny, no problerm with that (below) here: `$ bash --version  
GNU bash, Version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` what do you get for `echo {2010..2017}`?

Comment: Hmmm, I have GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Comment: Oh and for echo {2010..2017}, I get {2010..2017}.

Comment: Any globbing settings ( http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html )  changed, or just need a bash update?

Comment: Works for me with the exact same `bash` version. *When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth* Sol the improbable explanation is that you are somehow running some other shell (`dash` or else) and not `bash`. Can you have your script issue `ls -l /proc/$$/exe`?

Comment: `ls -l /proc/$$/exe`  =  tcsh.  I'm guessing that's my problem right there.

Answer (score 0):

You *are* really close. you just forget the 'do', like

```
#!/bin/bash
# if ! echo {2010..2017}| grep 2015; then echo "your globbing needs an update"; exit 1; fi 
for months in "11_Nov" "12_Dec" "01_Jan" "02_Feb" "03_Mar" "04_Apr"
do
  wget ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/NOAA/G02158/masked/{2010..2017}/"$months"/*.tar
done
```

Comment: Shoot, sorry.  The 'do' is in my script, I just forgot to include in my question.  I still get the error:  No such directory ‘DATASETS/NOAA/G02158/masked/{2010..2017}/12_Dec’.